# regex help with getting tag content in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, title

so I have the code

```
function getTagContent($string, $tagname) {

    $pattern = "/<$tagname.*?>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);


    print_r($matches);

}
```

and then I call

```
$url = "http://www.freakonomics.com/2008/09/24/wall-street-jokes-please/";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
getTagContent($html,"title");
```

but then it shows that there are no matches, while if you open the source of the url there clearly exist a title tag....

what did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Is `$html` supposed to appear out of thin air? :)

Comment: oh sorry see edits...i added $html

Comment: Is there any code converting the `$url` into `$html`? :) have you verified that `$html` does actually contain the `<title>` (not by visiting url, but by outputting it from your code)?

Comment: yes $html is displaying properly: see edits

Comment: [Dont use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try DOM

```
$url  = "http://www.freakonomics.com/2008/09/24/wall-street-jokes-please/";
$doc  = new DOMDocument();
$dom  = $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
  echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'title' tag is not on the same line as its closing tag, so your preg_match doesn't find it.

In Perl, you can add a /s switch to make it slurp the whole input as though on one line: I forget whether preg_match will let you do so or not.

But this is just one of the reasons why parsing XML and variants with regexp is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the title is spread on multiple lines. You need to add the option `s` so that the dot will also match any line returns.

```
$pattern = "/<$tagname.*?>(.*)<\/$tagname>/s";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your php function `getTagContent` like this:

```
function getTagContent($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = '/<'.$tagname.'[^>]*>(.*?)<\/'.$tagname.'>/is';
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

It is **important** to use non-greedy match all `.*?` for matching text between start and end of tag and equally important is to use flags `s` for DOTALL (matches new line as well) and `i` for ignore case comparison.